# How to check process log while using iAP protocol MFI?

Tags: swift, external-accessory, mfi

I have all the permission to do MFI, i am developing an ios application in swift which will speak with accessory connected to the device(iphone/ipad).

Question:
How can i debug or how can i check process flow by the perticular device(iphone/ipad)